# what is the equivalant of RxJava Observable and FlatMap in Kotlin coroutine Flow

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

Hi I have a rxJava observable and Flatmap which I want to convert to kotlin coroutine Flow.

rxJava observable

```
val startFuellingObservable: Observable<Void>
```

subscription / flatmap

```
subscriptions += view.startFuellingObservable
        .onBackpressureLatest()
        .doOnNext { view.showLoader(false) }
        .flatMap {
            if (!hasOpenInopIncidents()) {
                 //THIS API CALL RETURNS RX OBSERVABLE
                startFuellingUseCase.execute(equipmentProvider.get()) 
            } else {
                val incidentOpenResponse = GenericResponse(false)
                incidentOpenResponse.error = OPEN_INCIDENTS
                Observable.just(incidentOpenResponse)
            }
        }
        .subscribe(
            { handleStartFuellingClicked(view, it) },
            { onStartFuellingError(view) }
        )
```

I have changed my observable to Flow

```
val startFuellingObservable: Flow<Void>
```

as it is now Flow

I am able to do this

```
view.startFuellingObservable
            .onEach { view.showLoader(false) }
```

*** I have made the API call to return Flow instead of observable

But I am not sure how to do the rest of the flatmap using Flow

Could you please suggest how to do the same code using Flow please

Thanks
R

Comment: So the reason the type is Void is that it doesn't actually contain data, but is simply declaring the event of a returned API call without passing the data?

Comment: Hi reason why it is void is as it is linked to a button click
    @Override
    public Observable<Void> getStartFuellingObservable() {
        return RxView.clicks(dataViewHolder.btnStartFuelling);
    }

Comment: please correct me if my understanding is wrong

Comment: There is `flatMapConcat` for your use case, but the docs say its use should be discouraged and I don't really understand how `map` could be used in a clearer way as they suggest. It's also still experimental, so using it would require using `@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi`. As for the Void, in Kotlin, Unit is typically used instead.

Comment: can you suggest on how my code should be changed please and I will try that

Comment: You can replace `onBackpressureLatest()` with `conflate()` and `flatMap` with `flatMapConcat`. The subscribe part would be done separately by launching a coroutine and using `collect` on the Flow. But as I mentioned, the docs for `flatMapConcat` say they discourage using it and I don't understand why exactly.

Comment: Hello @Tenfour04 i tried that and it gives me an error - Type mismatch.
Required:
Flow<TypeVariable(R)>
Found:
Unit

Comment: this is what I tried

Comment: view.startFuellingObservable
            .conflate()
            .flatMapConcat {
                if (!hasOpenInopIncidents()) {
                    startFuellingUseCaseCoroutine(StartFuellingUseCaseCoroutine.Params(equipmentProvider.get())) {

                    }
                }
            }

Comment: startFuellingUseCaseCoroutine returns Flow<GenericResponse>

Comment: It's hard for me to say without knowing the return types of all the different functions you're calling.

Answer (score 4):

late answer but I hope it may help others.
First of all, there is a Flow from kotlin Concurrent so you definitely need to import

```
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.5.0'
```

which belongs to import `kotlinx.coroutines.flow`

1. `Observables<T>` from RxJava will be `Flow<T>`
2. Rxjava FlatMap is FlatMapMerge in Kotlin Flow API

FlatMapMerge example:

```
val startTime = System.currentTimeMillis() // remember the start time 
(1..3).asFlow().onEach { delay(100) } // a number every 100 ms 
    .flatMapMerge { requestFlow(it) }                                                                           
    .collect { value -> // collect and print 
        println("$value at ${System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime} ms from start") 
    } 

result:
1: First at 136 ms from start
2: First at 231 ms from start
3: First at 333 ms from start
1: Second at 639 ms from start
2: Second at 732 ms from start
3: Second at 833 ms from start
```

there are 3 types of FlatMap in Flow API

**FlatMapConcat**

This operator is sequential and paired. Once the outerFlow emits once, the innerFlow must emit once before the final result is collected. Once either flow emits a Nth time, the other flow must emit a Nth time before the Nth flatMapResult is collected.

**FlatMapMerge**

This operator has the least restrictions on emissions, but can result in too many emissions. Every time the outerFlow emits a value, each of the innerFlow emissions are flatMapped from that value into the final flatMapResult to be collected. The final emission count is a multiplication of innerFlow and outerFlow emissions.

**FlatMapLatest**

This operator cares only about the latest emitted results and does not process old emissions. Every time the outerFlow emits a value, it is flatMapped with the latest innerFlow value. Every time the innerFlow emits a value, it is flatMapped with the latest outerFlow value. Thus the final emission count is a value between zero and innerFlow emissions times outerFlow emissions.

Comment: use `flowOf(it)` instead of `requestFlow(it)` if requestFlow is not available